# Fixing preview on SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Passing data in preview with a viewModel is easy but how do i pass data when i have some kind of generic data? Can't find a proper answer on google. In this particular app i'm implementing the Router design pattern can be found here (https://github.com/obvios/Routing). The preview is asking me to pass an argument for parameter ''router'' but this is quite different like when you do with a viewModel normally i'd pass viewModel: ExampleViewModel(). So i don't know what exactly to pass in the Preview? Autocomplete is not helpful.

[image]

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import Routing

 struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RoutingView(BasicsRouter.self) { router in
            BasicsView(router: router)
        }
    }
 }


 struct BasicsView: View {
    @StateObject var router: Router<BasicsRouter>
    init(router: Router<BasicsRouter>) {
        _router = StateObject(wrappedValue: router)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
 }

 #Preview {
    BasicsView()
 }
```

Comment: Your code is not equal to the image. Try to avoid images instead of code.

Comment: If they don’t provide an initial user for preview then previews aren’t supported. You would have to create  a RoutingView in the Preview

Comment: `@StateObject` is for when you need reference semantics in a `@State`, i.e. using a delegate or Combine pipeline, doesn't look like you need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to pass ContentView in preview:

```
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```